# Launching multiple (3) programs simultaneously via a batch file doesn't work... sort of

Tags: windows, batch-file, windows-10

I am trying to launch 3 different software programs at the same time with one single batch file, but the problem is that the batch file doesn't open them at the same time.

The first program gets launched (Affinity Photo), but the second program (RICOH THETA Stitcher) doesn't launch until I close Affinity Photo.

This is an overview of the programs that I want to launch (at the same time):

Affinity Photo, RICOH THETA Stitcher and 3DVista Virtual Tour.

3DVista Virtual Tour doesn't launch at all, even with a 'sort of working' script (giving me no error messages) - it only opens if the script that I have in my batch file is to open just this software.

Does anybody know how I can launch 3 different programs at the same time via a batch file (and not - one opens, exit that and then the second opens etc...)?

I tried two different scripts for this to work.

The first one was this:

```
@echo off
cd "C:\Program Files\Affinity\Photo"
start Photo.exe
cd "C:\Program Files\RICOH THETA Stitcher"
start RICOH THETA Stitcher.exe
cd "C:\Program Files\3DVista\3DVista Virtual Tour"
start 3DVista Virtual Tour.exe
exit
```

This script opened Affinity Photo but gave me an error message on the two other programs.

[Error message for 3DVista Virtual Tour](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vZa7P.png)

[Error message for RICOH THETA Stitcher](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OJxAx.png)

Here are the locations for the files:

[Affinity Photo path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sCECt.png)

[RICOH THETA Stitcher path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gEXrI.png)

[3DVista Virtual Tour path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LfITc.png)

I tried a different script which kind of worked, but didn't at the same time:

```
@echo off
cmd /C "C:\Program Files\Affinity\Photo\Photo.exe" && "C:\Program Files\RICOH THETA Stitcher\RICOH THETA Stitcher.exe" && "C:\Program Files\3DVista\3DVista Virtual Tour\3DVista Virtual Tour.exe"
exit
```

This script opened Affinity Photo but didn't open the RICOH THETA Stitcher until after I closed Affinity Photo, and after I closed the RICOH THETA Stitcher, the 3DVista Virtual Tour program didn't launch at all.

(This is my first post here, so tell me if there's something I need to improve when it comes to asking questions!)

Comment: Make sure to read the documentation for start carefully (`start /?`). You need double quotes. For example, `start "" /b "RICOH THETA Stitcher.exe"` is probably what you want.

Comment: The only issue I see with the initial code snippet, is missing quotes around your executable names, ```start "" "RICOH THETA Stitcher.exe"```, and ```start "" "3DVista Virtual Tour.exe"```. _(Although I'd not waste time using `CD` at all)_. The following shorter, single line, batch file example, should do it ```@Start "Photo" "%ProgramFiles%\Affinity\Photo\Photo.exe" & Start "Stitcher" "%ProgramFiles%\RICOH THETA Stitcher\RICOH THETA Stitcher.exe" & Start "Tour" "%ProgramFiles%\3DVista\3DVista Virtual Tour\3DVista Virtual Tour.exe"```

Answer (score 0):

The code snippet:

```bash
@Start "Photo" "%ProgramFiles%\Affinity\Photo\Photo.exe" & Start "Stitcher" "%ProgramFiles%\RICOH THETA Stitcher\RICOH THETA Stitcher.exe" & Start "Tour" "%ProgramFiles%\3DVista\3DVista Virtual Tour\3DVista Virtual Tour.exe"
```

Worked like a charm!

Thanks [Compo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6738015/compo)!